# Sharepoint 2010 uploading a xml form to document library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to upload a xml document generated from an infopath 2010 form to a document library. The code is shown below

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(this.Context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri))
                {  
                    sb.AppendLine("site URL : " + site.Url);
                    SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
                    //SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb;
                    sb.AppendLine("Web URL : " + web.Url);      
                    SPDocumentLibrary docLib = web.Lists["Supplier Requests Library"] as SPDocumentLibrary;            
                    string destUrl = docLib.RootFolder.Url + "/" + countryName + "/" + supplierCategory + "/" + supplierNumber + " " + supplierName + ".xml";
                    sb.AppendLine("destination URL : " + destUrl);                      
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    SPFile destFile = docLib.RootFolder.Files.Add(destUrl.Trim(), document, true,"",false);
                    destFile.Update();
                    docLib.Update();           
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;                     
                    sb.AppendLine("document uploaded successfully");
                }
```

I get the form submission failed error, but when i check the library i have my xml document uploaded succesfully.
The error was :

```
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.


at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
   at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtilityInternal.SendResponse(HttpContext context, Int32 code, String strBody)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.HandleAccessDenied(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.HandleAccessDenied(Exception ex)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.SetListProps(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bMigrate)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.Update(Boolean bFromMigration)
   at SupplierWebService.SubmitFormData(Byte[] document)
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at SupplierWebService.SubmitFormData(Byte[] document)
   at SupplierWebService.SubmitFromData(XmlDocument document)
```

I ran the code with elevated privileges to get over this error and was successful but now the created by field shows System account for every document created, and i cannot filter the data to generate a view to show the documents created by current logged in user.

Please suggest some work arounds to get over this issue. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not call `doclib.Update()`. You are not changing any list *metadata*, you are adding *data*.

Also, why are you turning on unsafe updates?

Comment: This document is being uploaded from an aspx page which hosts the infopath form and this page resides under the root folder, this upload is happening outside of the sharepoint security context.

Comment: I removed library update.I realized now it was not necessary.Thanks for the insight! The issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens when you are doing a redirect. Can you check if that is the case? [Sample thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopment/thread/aa12b2e3-d9b2-490b-911b-423b6edbbb0d) if it provides any pointers.

Comment: Nope I am not using any redirect here.. I am aware of the problem with Response.End(). I was having a print button in my infopath button which uses the response object to render a pdf version of the form. There i had to replace response.end() with HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()

Comment: It definitely seems to be a permission issue as there is a call to Access Denied happening which is redirecting causing the thread abort. You may need to tweak there check the permissions for the user you are having issue with on the library?

Comment: A similar issue if it helps you - [MSDN Forums] (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopment/thread/caae8e3c-8d1d-4d95-a734-3f6c2c31c457)

Comment: Yes, I was able to do this without any issue using the sharepoint admin account. I have set the permission for domain users as Contribute.When i set the permission for domain users to Design i dont get this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I felt removing doclib.Update() as suggested by Ondrej was the better solution.